# ReactiveVar not re-rendering React component

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm quite new to React in Meteor.

TL;DR : In my data container, changing the value of my ReactiveVar do not rerender my view.

I've got this code :

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

// Mail composer - interface for generating enews
class MailComposer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleSubmit( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const text = this.refs.mailText.value.trim(),
          title = this.refs.mailTitle.value.trim(),
          rcpts = this.refs.mailRecpts.value.trim();

    console.log(text, title, rcpts);

    if ( text && title && rcpts ) {
      // ...
      this.props.hasTestedIt.set( true );
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this);
    $( this.refs.textArea ).autosize();
  }

  getBtnText () {
    return ( this.props.hasTestedIt.get() ? "Send it" : "Test it" );
  }

  render() {
    let self = this;
    Tracker.autorun(function(){
      console.log(self.props.hasTestedIt.get());
    });

    return (
      <div className="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div className="panel-heading">
          <h3 className="panel-title">Mail composer</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="panel-body">
          <form className="form-group" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <div className="input-group">
              <span className="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Title</span>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="mailTitle" />
            </div>
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="js-recipients">Recipients:</label>
            <select className="form-control" width="width: initial;" id="js-recipients" ref="mailRecpts">
              <option>Admins</option>
              <option>All</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="comment">Text:</label>
            <textarea className="form-control" rows="5" ref="mailText"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
              {this.getBtnText()}
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MailComposer.propTypes = {
  hasTestedIt: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default createContainer( () => {
  return {
    hasTestedIt: new ReactiveVar( false )
  };
}, MailComposer);`
```

But when I set my `ReactiveVar` prop in my submit handler, the text returned by the `getBtnText` method in the button do not change. I've tried to put the ternary directly inside the HTML, but I got the same result.
The var is correctly setted to true, as the autorun correctly log me the change.

In another component, from which this one has been copied, I do correctly rerender the component, but using a `.fetch()` on a `find` to map the returned array in a `renderTasks` method which render a list of new components.

What am I missing please ? And how could I fix it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component doesn't update because the passed `hasTestedIt` prop is not changed itself. It's the value it holds that changed.

Watch the value you are actually interested in instead.

```
// Declare the reactive source somewhere appropriately.
const hasTestedIt = new ReactiveVar( false );

// Watch its value instead.
export default createContainer( () => {
  return {
    hasTestedIt: hasTestedIt.get()
  };
}, MailComposer);`
```

Note that it is now the value passed to `MailComposer`, not a `ReactiveVar` that can be referenced to update the value anymore. How do we update it in this case?

One simplest approach is to pass the `hasTestedIt` as well as before, though this wouldn't be my personal recommendation.

```
// Watch its value instead.
export default createContainer( () => {
  return {
    // Reactive source that triggers re-rendering.
    valueOfHasTestedIt: hasTestedIt.get(),
    // Provided for the contained component to reference to set new values.
    // Leaving this alone doesn't trigger re-rendering!
    hasTested
  };
}, MailComposer);
```

It's not elegant IMO. Another one is to pass a callback function to `MailComposer` which can be used to update the value.

```
const updateHasTestedIt = ( value ) => hasTestedIt.set( value );

// Watch its value instead.
export default createContainer( () => {
  return {
    hasTestedIt: hasTestedIt.get(),
    updateHasTestedIt,
  };
}, MailComposer);

class MailComposer extends Component {
  ...
  handleSubmit( event ) {
    ...
    this.props.updateHasTestedIt( true );
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

It's better this time.

It is possible to develop more, but it really depends on your preference for your very application. You and only you can make the design decision.

Comment: When you asy to pass the `hasTestedIt` as well as before, you mean to pass directly the value in the container ? If so, changing the value could still start a rerender though it's not from a reactiveVar ?

Help much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @David Panart, Yes. If the returned value of `createContainer` is not changed in a shallow comparison, no re-rendering will be triggered despite `hasTestedIt` is a reactive source.